# Limit ABPeoplePicker to just one group, not all contacts

Tags: ios, iphone, contacts, abpeoplepickerview

In one of my apps I am saving contacts in the address book and putting them in a group I create to differentiate them from the rest of the contacts.

Is there a way I could show all the people from that group, but not all the rest of the AB with an ABPeoplePicker or similar view??

I'm just using native contacts to save me the hassle of coding all the database and UI stuff from scratch, I don't really need the contacts to be accessible from outside of the app. So if that isn't possible I guess I should just create my own contacts system, right? any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked on similar problem. But rather than creating the whole contact system what we did is ..... just created over own picker..... using a tableViewController and then after we used ABPersonViewController and other things as it is..... yes, for our specific contacts(as you have group) we had to store the recordId's in a small database.....